# Get erc 20 balance in solidty

Tags: erc-20

Hi' I'm trying to get a balance of erc 20 tokens of given address in my solidity sc, but it always gives me back 0. I tried to play around with it for hours and can't find where the mistake lays. Could someone help, please ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract ERC20 { 
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public; 
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
}
contract TestErc20{

 function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    ERC20 t = ERC20(0xCCF1C01067E4200F0E4ddb1f2f3cCEa85A18aa2C);
   return (t.balanceOf(0xb06029664056f44437F4E82cFB2D6B153513F0B8));
  }
}
```

Comment: @Aquila is right, your functions look just fine. Just to be sure, though, you might want to change `constant` in the ERC20contract to `view` and remove the brackets around the return value, so you have  
`return t.balanceOf(0xb06029664056f44437F4E82cFB2D6B153513F0B8);`

Answer (score 1):

Based on provided code I can only say that there is no transfer or token's mint to the address, that is why balance is zero